# Localization of site title / headline and slogan

Tags: joomla-3.x, language

How could I localized the site title / headline and slogan of a Joomla site. I have got localized menus with localized pages, but I have no idea how could I make site title multilingual?

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PHP, you can get the current language in Joomla like this:

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$current = $lang->getTag();
```

You can then use an if-else statement to display localized title:

```
  if ($current == "en-GB") { 
      // English title here
  } 
  elseif ($current == "es-ES") { 
      // Spanish title here
  }
  elseif ($current == "nb-NO") { 
      // Norwegian title here
  }
  else { 
      // Default title here (in case none of the above matches)
  }
```

This code can be used in your templates `index.php` file, in a module that supports PHP code (e.g. [Custom HTML Advanced](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/custom-html-advanced)), or in any module using [Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/sourcerer) to include the PHP code.

Comment: Great. It worked. I installed Sourcerer  and Custom HTML Advanced modules. I placed such code there: {source}
<?php
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$current = $lang->getTag();
?>
{/source}
<h1 class="stl-headline" data-left="1.23%">
    <a href="/">

{source}
<?php
  if ($current == "en-GB") { 
      // English title here
    echo "English title";
  } 
  elseif ($current == "es-ES") { 
    echo "Spanish title";
  }
  else { 
    // default title
    echo "Мобилен Масаж";
  } 
?>
{/source}
</a>
</h1>

Answer (score 2):

If you place the title / slogan in a module, you can assign a language to the module, so it will only appear with the desired language.

Comment: Yeah, this is a solution. But when I enter some new pages, I have to assign the correct module to them. It is much manual work. But Valentin, thanks for the solution!

Comment: A multilingual website is a lot of manual work indeed! But with this solution you have everything configurative (without writing any code). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can override or insert your own keys when going to Extensions > Languages > Overrides. After that, you only need to put these keys into your site configuration.

If the key isn't translated, you may have to make/override a plugin.

Comment: I saw my template uses this:   <?php echo $this->params->get('siteTitle'); ?> And I overrided siteTitle as you described. But It did not change the site title. If it worked, it would be the best solution! Clear and easy to extend!